# Doing a SHA256withRSA with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to do a Google oAuth2 method in Google Apps Script by constructing the descripbed JWS/JWT stuff.

Now, I can read a key file from Drive or maybe from another source, but how should I sign it with this file? Are there any methods or JavaSCript pieces to do this?

```
function Auth20(user) {
var header = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify( {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"} ) );
var claimdata = {
"iss":"1002979611916q0iraclc6q33xxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
             "prn": user,
             "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
             "aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
               "exp":new Date().getTime()/1000,
               "iat":(new Date().getTime()/1000)+3600 
              }
var claim = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify( claimdata ))

 var jws = header+"."+claim;
 var jwsbytes = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < jws.length; ++i)
 {
 jwsbytes.push(jws.charCodeAt(i));
 }
  var key = DriveApp.getFileById("0B_5HSTQXtXmsU29fTE5xNWhvOVE").getBlob()
```

Comment: Hi @Riel, have you found a solution to your issue?

Comment: This is now build in into Google Apps Script and therefore solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function like the one below should do the trick. Two things to note:

1) The Private Key needs to be in the format of a PRIVATE KEY not an RSA PRIVATE KEY. If your key is the latter, you'll need openssl, which would allow you to run the following for your key stored in the `private.pem` file. Note also the string format with explicit `\n` when used within GAS:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in private.pem -outform pem -nocrypt -out newPrivate.pem
```

2) `Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe()` may return terminal padding in the form of `=` signs. These need to be removed, hence my inclusion of steps with `.replace(/=+$/, '')`

Putting it all together:

```
function Auth20(user) {
  var privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n{privatekeyhere}\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  var header = {
    alg: 'RS256',
    typ: 'JWT'
  };
  var now = new Date();
  var claimSet = {
    iss: {your_iss},
    prn: user,
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
    aud:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    exp: (now.getTime() / 1000) + 3000,
    iat: now.getTime() / 1000
  };
  var toSign = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(JSON.stringify(header)) + '.' + Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(JSON.stringify(claimSet));
  toSign = toSign.replace(/=+$/, '');
  var signatureBytes = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(toSign, privateKey);
  var signature = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(signatureBytes);
  signature = signature.replace(/=+$/, '');
  return toSign + '.' + signature;
};
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. Since the encoding method was added to the Utilities class it is doable! Makes this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

i use kjur  https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/

```
load('auth/jsrsasign-latest-all-min.js');

 var sHead=JSON.stringify({"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"});    
       var iat=timeStampf();
       var exp=iat+3600;
       var sPayload=JSON.stringify({
                  "iss":client_email,
                  "scope":scope,                 
                  "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
                  "exp":exp,
                  "iat":iat
                });    
      var sJWS = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", sHead,sPayload, private_key);
```

sJWS variable is head(base64).playload(base64).token(base64)
token is generated with sha256withrsa "RS256"